# Flutter Rive - animation doesn't change when changing Number input in state machine

Tags: flutter, state-machine, rive

I tried to play with boolean input and it worked really nice, but changing number input won't change the animation at all.
I made sure couple of times animation is right, state machine name is correct and input name is correct as well.

I tried changing `SMIInput<num>? _hoursInput;` into `SMIInput<SMINumber>? _hoursInput;` and than in casting integer as SMINumber like so: `_hoursInput?.value = 100 as SMINumber`
I tried using double instead of SMINumber. I tried assigning value with setState and without setState.
I made sure the State Machine Animations are in fact depended on the number value.
Nothing works.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:rive/rive.dart';

/// An example showing how to drive two boolean state machine inputs.
class Eldey extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map data;
  const Eldey({Key? key, required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EldeyState createState() => _EldeyState();
}

class _EldeyState extends State<Eldey> {
  /// Tracks if the animation is playing by whether controller is running.
  bool get isPlaying => _controller?.isActive ?? false;

  Artboard? _riveArtboard;
  StateMachineController? _controller;
  SMIInput<num>? _hoursInput;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Load the animation file from the bundle, note that you could also
    // download this. The RiveFile just expects a list of bytes.
    rootBundle.load('assets/animations/testing_3.riv').then(
      (data) async {
        // Load the RiveFile from the binary data.
        final file = RiveFile.import(data);

        // The artboard is the root of the animation and gets drawn in the
        // Rive widget.
        final artboard = file.mainArtboard;
        var controller = StateMachineController.fromArtboard(artboard, 'State Machine');
        if (controller != null) {
          artboard.addController(controller);
          _hoursInput = controller.findInput('Hours');
        }
        setState(() => _riveArtboard = artboard);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int time = int.parse(widget.data['ftime'].substring(0,2));
    if(time > 9  && time < 17){
      setState(() {
        _hoursInput?.value = 100.0;
      });
    }
    return Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: _riveArtboard == null
          ? const SizedBox()
          : SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Rive(
                artboard: _riveArtboard!,
              ),
            ),
          )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you checked `_hoursInput = controller.findInput('Hours');` is null or not. im getting null while finding inputs

Comment: Yeah I checked, weirdly it is able to work with input when it is a trigger, but not when it's a number or boolean. I just switched to trigger for now, but maybe SMIInput<num> isn't right type for it. Not sure, will have to dig deeper, for now I just set my statemachine differently, using triggers.

Comment: i replaced `num` with `double` and it is working well

Comment: Will check it asap!